# Ajax is undefined

Tags: ajax.net

This is my code. When I run this I get an error: "Ajax is undefined". The error line is highlighted by black letters.

```
function funGetName()
{
    var id=document.getElementById("Cust_Id").value;
    var URL="Default.aspx?TODO=getName&custId="+id;
    alert(id);
    var ajax=new Ajax.Request(URL,
    {
        method:'get'
    });
}
```

Comment: did you solve this? if not are you certain that the ajax js file has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the opening brace on the same line, after `URL,`. It may be a semicolon insertion problem.

i.e.:

```
var ajax=new Ajax.Request(URL, {
    method:'get'
});
```

Comment: even if i comment all the lines except var ajax=new Ajax.Request() i got the same error.  so might be from hardware components like versions:  i'm using vs 2005 version 8.0 framework 2.0